# adding SupportFragment to a non-fragment-extended activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a working map activity which shows Sydney on google maps:

```
public class LocMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_lox_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

and the fragment itself looks like this:

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="300sp"
      tools:context="com.example.tarsi.cyou.AllLoxMap"/>
```

i need a map in a smaller size in another activity.

My goal is to put this map into an activity which already extends to AppCompatActivity, so I can't extend it to any fragment. The codes I found use the getMap() method which has been deprecated.

Which is the easiest way?

Thanks

Comment: It's the same procedure

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity, FragmentActivity <-- Class cannot extend multiple classes

Comment: You don't need to extend `FragmentActivity` to have `Google Maps` inside `Activity`

Comment: What user interface could I use that has this in it:           android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" if not fragment
?